# Email obfuscstion on a site using the <app-obfuscate-email email=

Tags: email, html-email, obfuscation

I totally understand this is a broad subject, but I'm not seeking advice on what's the best technique rather than on the specific implementation I've seen today for the first time ever.

Basically I came across a site where the email of the person I was trying to contact forced me to  setup the local mail.app (on the mac) which is not setup (I use Outlook), meaning that I couldn't contact this person.

I therefore inspected the element, to find out nothing but a plain image, which was strange, because that alone could not trigger the mail app to open.
Since there where not any JavaScript code attached, I decided to look at the source, and I found out the following `<app-obfuscate-email email=....` tag which is something not standard.

I tried to Google for it, but cannot find any information. Do you guys know anything more about this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some more info e.g. page URL?
You can define customized tags using JavaScript https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/extending-the-html-by-creating-custom-tags--cms-28622

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the site. I've seen it here: https://www.stephaneplazaimmobilier.com/immobilier-acheter/2184149/ancienne-ferme-renovee-de-216-m2-habitable-studio and your hint suggested me what to look for ... apparently this is done with Vue, which I've never used before. Thanks.